# JS code not executed

Tags: javascript, primefaces, linechart

I'm currently trying to call a JS script in order to export chart from primefaces chart component.
 The problem is that the base64str variable seem to be null, and the responsible script for filling this value is not called for some reason :

xhtml code :

```
<p:chart id="chart" type="line"  widgetVar="chart" model="#{cont.lineModel}"  style="height:550px;width:1800px">
           <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{cont.itemSelect}" update="growl" />                             
    </p:chart>
    <p:commandButton id="exp" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink"
            onclick="exportChart();" actionListener="#{cont.submittedBase64Str}" 
           />
        <h:inputHidden id="b64" value="#{cont.base64Str}" />                     


<script type="text/javascript">
        function exportChart() {
        img = chart.exportAsImage();
        document.getElementById('hform:b64').value = img.src;

        }
    </script>
```

Controller :

```
public void submittedBase64Str(ActionEvent event){
// You probably want to have a more comprehensive check here. 
// In this example I only use a simple check
if(base64Str.split(",").length > 1){
    String encoded = base64Str.split(",")[1];
    byte[] decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);
    // Write to a .png file
    try {
        RenderedImage renderedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
        ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", new File("D:\\out.png")); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onclick` attribute to `onstart`.

```
    <p:commandButton id="exp" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink"
  onstart="exportChart();" actionListener="#{cont.submittedBase64Str}" />
```

That should call the JS function.

**EDIT**

Also, you need to define `img` and `chart` in your function.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, can you put an alert() right at the start of your function?

Comment: The alert showed up only at the beginning of the script. It seems that the code : img = chart.exportAsImage(); was not executed.Then the actionListener is executed.

Comment: I have never used JS to code, so can you help me to define img and chart. Thank you :)

Comment: What is chart? What object is it? These are the fundamentals of JS.

Comment: The object is LineModelChart (as it is defined in the controller). I tried chart = new LineModelChart(); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`chart` object is the PrimeFaces JS widget. You define `widgetVar`:

```
<p:chart ... widgetVar="chart"
```

And then you can get the chart object in your JS code like this:

```
PF('chart')
```

You need to use the `PF` function to get widgets since PrimeFaces 4.0.

As a side note, it's better to make your `img` variable local instead of global:

```
var img = chart.exportAsImage();
```

Now `img` is defined only in the scope of the function.